# Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 does not show up after installing

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins

I am running on Mac OS X 10.5.8.

The problem is that the "g" toolbar icon does not show up after I finish installing GPE 4.2 and GWT SDK 2.4 plugin. When I go to "preferences", there should be a google tab, but that does not show up either.

There was no problems with the installation. If I go to "Install new software..."->"already installed...", both GPE 4.2 and GWT SDK 2.4 are listed.

Can anyone kindly help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you glanced at the **Customize Perspective** dialog (**Window** --> **Customize Perspective** in the main menu)? Check out the **Tool Bar Visibility** tab: is the **Google** tree item there, with **GDTPulldown** item as its child?

Comment: I misread your question and thought you were referring to the blue **G** in the toolbar when I made the comment above. Still, its presence is also an indicator of correct installation.

Comment: The Google tree item does not exist in the Tool Bar Visibility tab. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the plugins to no avail. The Eclipse download I used is Eclipse Classic 4.2 Mac OS X 32bit.

Comment: Hmm ... I usually start with the **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers** package and have never had an issue. Maybe a GPE dependency is missing from the Classic version and is not properly resolved during the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac was 64bit. Needed to install 64bit version of Eclipse.